# Nodejs with Cassandra - insert and get new object back

Tags: node.js, cassandra

I'm using the DataStax Cassandra driver with NodeJS, and I would like to know if there's a way to get the new created object back after I add it to the DB?
I'm familiar with such an option in Mongo using Mongoose, but could not find an equivalent in Cassandra, does this mean I need to select it manually after I add it?

Comment: I've checked driver that You use and other packages. In fact all of them require to do select query after insert. If You don't require id of inserted record You can just response with Your data (that You pass to insertion) after insert. But if You require last inserted record's id that's not possible. I recommend You to add `uuid` field to tables and using `uuid.v4()` have some custom id. ;)

Comment: But You can use ORM: http://express-cassandra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/ some kind of mongoose, sequelize (;

Comment: @num8er, So there's no way to save and get it in a single call? I must perform a manual select?

Comment: Yes, it is. Or use ORM that will keep the structure in instance. Just look at `express-cassandra`

Comment: @num8er, another question, not directly related, I would like to know if there's an option using the DataStax driver to close the Cassandra connection? (not shutdown) also, is there a way to specify the number of execution retries?

Comment: In fact it's not using http(s)-request-like connection. So it will keep connection open. But why You want to close connection until first demand? NodeJS is not like PHP where You connect db every time when script runs from top to bottom. In case of nodejs everything must keep connections alive to ensure fast operation on db. But You can force to close connection by destroying db connection variable `delete connection` and do a connection every time when You need it. But believe me: 1. it will be slow, 2. You cannot control when to close and when to open in case of many parallel requests.

Comment: @num8er, thank you! what about specifying the number of query execution retries?

Comment: why to retry? if db responses with error it will not be successful if You try again and it's not good practice to keep "ddos"-ing database with repeating queries.

Comment: @num8er, in case a node is down or not.

Comment: in case of cassandra node will die, so will get errors and it's not good to retry querying. it will make high load on app instance. so better to attach `winston` and use some log alerting service to send email when it happens to fix that issue.